# How to use philsturgeon codeigniter assets?

Tags: php, codeigniter, assets

I try to use [philsturgeon CI assets](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-asset#readme) in my project and face this error :

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function css() in /var/www/html/staging/psms_dev/application/views/login.php on line 6**

The code that i use is:

```
<?php echo css('style.css'); ?>
```

This is my folder structure:

```
application  
system  
assets  
--css  
--js  
--images
```

and this is my assets.php config

```
$config['asset_dir'] = '/assets/';
$config['asset_url'] = config_item('base_url').'assets/';
```

I use CodeIgniter 2.0.2. Hope you guys can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is /assets/ supposed to be on your server's root directory? If so, you need to chmod it as folders on the root are generally restricted. If not, then you might need to get rid of the first forward slash in `'/assets/'`

Comment: thanks. and one more it seems i forgot to autoload the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the leading `/` from `/assets/`:

```
$config['asset_dir'] = 'assets/';
```